# Video streaming through html and ajax

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

I am trying  this code  for video streaming  ...when i send the data through ajax and receive that data on same page video play properly..but when i try to play on other page or server side it gives error...

```
<!--This is my client side code-->

    <html>
      <body>

     <div id="mine">
       <video id="video" width="500" height="500"  autoplay="true"></video>
       <video id="video1" width="500" height="500" autoplay="true"> </video>
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         var str;
        (function(){
          var video=document.getElementById('video'),
          vendorUrl =window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          navigator.getMedia=navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.nsGetUserMedia;
                         navigator.getMedia({
                         video:true,
                         audio:true
                     },function(stream){
                      video.src=vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                      str=vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                     video.play();
                     },function(error){
                         alert("error")
                     });
             })();

        var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
        function processresponse(){
             if(ajax.readyState===4){
                 var rse=ajax.responseText;
                 var vid=document.getElementById("video1");
                 vid.src=rse;
                 vid.play();
            }
        }
        function show(){
             ajax.onreadystatechange=processresponse;
            ajax.open("Post","server.jsp",true);
            ajax.send(str);

        }
         timer = setInterval(show,10000 );

       </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

server.jsp....

```
   <%   
   InputStream is=request.getInputStream();     
    byte[] bt=new byte[1000];
     is.read(bt);
    String req=new String(bt);
   out.println(req );
    %>
<!--This is the code which is giving error......-->
 <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.BufferedOutputStream"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.FileOutputStream"%>   
 <%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
 <html>
      <body>
            <video id='video1' width='500' height='500'  autoplay='true'>
            </video>
  <%     
      InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
      byte[] bt=new byte[1000];
      is.read(bt);
      String req=new String(bt); 

 %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var vid=document.getElementById("video1");
        alert('<%=req%>');
        vid.src='<%=req%>';
        vid.play();
      </script>
   </body>
```